# How to show items from specific index in a listview builder flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to start showing the list items from index 5

```
ListView.builder(
itemCount: items.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  return ListTile(
    title: Text('${items[index]}'),
  );
},
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out

```
ListView.builder(
itemCount: items.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  if(index < 5) return SizedBox();
  return ListTile(
    title: Text('${items[index]}'),
  );
},
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can give it a try.
To only show specific items based on certain conditions, you can use the "Visibility" widget as the example shown below.

```
 ListView.builder(
      itemCount: items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Visibility(
          visible: index>5,
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text('${items[index]}'),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Hope this helps! :Ｄ

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider this approach, for me it's tested and proven.

Use this Package in your ListView Builder
[scrollable_positioned_list](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list)

The package comes with a property called `initialScrollIndex`, which allows you to set the index you want your list view to start from .

Worthy of note, the value of your `initialScrollIndex` must not be out of range, it's important you check the length of the data  before assigning a value to the `initialScrollIndex`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for

```
ListView.builder(
itemCount: items.length - 5,
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  return ListTile(
    title: Text(items[index+5].toString()),
  );
},
);
```